# MySQL randomized list with sequence in list

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-order-by

I have a table of students (id, name, project).  I'd like a ramdomized sequence of students whose projects are '%science%'.

`SELECT NAME, id FROM students WHERE project LIKE '%science%' ORDER BY RAND()`

Here's the complication: I'd like to get each student's "sequence number" in the randomized list.  This is what I have, and it isn't working.

```
SET @sequence=0;
SELECT @sequence:=@sequence+1 AS sequence, name, id
  FROM students
  WHERE project LIKE '%science%'
  ORDER BY RAND();
SELECT @sequence;
```

Could somebody please help fix this?

Run1:

```
1   486 Linda
2   307 Patricia
3   218 Barbara
4   713 Mary
```

Run2:

```
1   713 Mary
2   486 Linda
3   307 Patricia
4   218 Barbara
```

Gratitude,
Joanna

Answer (score 0):

MySQL user variables and `order by` are tricky. The [documentation says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

> HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY, when referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select expression list do not work as expected because the expression is evaluated on the client and thus can use stale column values from a previous row.

It is safer to `order by` in a subquery, then assign the variable:

```
SET @sequence=0;
SELECT @sequence:=@sequence+1 sequence, s.*
FROM (
    SELECT name, id 
    FROM students 
    WHERE project LIKE '%science%' 
    ORDER BY RAND()
) s;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a75b8bcafd0fbe1ca9ffeb69cbc967f)**:

Run 1:

```
sequence | name     |  id
-------: | :------- | --:
       1 | Linda    | 486
       2 | Patricia | 307
       3 | Mary     | 713
       4 | Barbara  | 218
```

Run 2:

```
sequence | name     |  id
-------: | :------- | --:
       1 | Barbara  | 218
       2 | Patricia | 307
       3 | Mary     | 713
       4 | Linda    | 486
```

---

Note that if you are running MySQL 8.0, this is much simpler (and efficiently) done with window functions:

```
    SELECT name, id, row_number() over(order by rand()) sequence
    FROM students 
    WHERE project LIKE '%science%' 
    ORDER BY sequence
```